# My flutter app is crashing the moment it launches with the following error:

Tags: android, flutter

After the app launches and exists instantly, the console says the following error:

I searched many solutions her and there but could not figure out anything.

Help is really appreciated. BTW, this is the only thing that is preventing me from releasing my app and publishing it. Thanks alot.

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(13552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13552): Process: com.comet.manga, PID: 13552
E/AndroidRuntime(13552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.comet.manga.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.comet.manga.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.comet.manga-3NMRdDTvHVRYO7itAb__EQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.comet.manga-3NMRdDTvHVRYO7itAb__EQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.comet.manga-3NMRdDTvHVRYO7itAb__EQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1226)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6431)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.comet.manga.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.comet.manga-3NMRdDTvHVRYO7itAb__EQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.comet.manga-3NMRdDTvHVRYO7itAb__EQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.comet.manga-3NMRdDTvHVRYO7itAb__EQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1148)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1218)
E/AndroidRuntime(13552):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: If it can't find your application class, odds are it isn't there. Why don't you try unzipping the apk and examining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is due to `Dex Error`,it can be resolved by enabling [multiDex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex). So in your `android/app` directory add these lines to the `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
  ....
```

Comment: I had multidex enabled, I just added the implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your app target **21 api level** and above **MultiDex is enabled by default**